# How to limit a certain page only for admin access with vue?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am a rookie about firebase and VUE

I have a project , in the backend page , there is a page call uploadProduct,I can upload products data to firestore and firebase to render front end product page.

My project is complete and I wanna know how to limit the uploadproductpage only for admin access.

I read all the firebase Docs still can‘t understand which syntax should I use

Now the UploadProduct I select for only sing in User to access

I have a idea, can I use vue router‘s beaforeeach syntax , then set a account call admin email and then use firebase auth to get currentuser email , if currentuser is the admin account. access

Can anyone know other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the enforcement on the backend, not the frontend, otherwise users would be able to (easily) circumvent it.

What you need to do is add access rules to the Firebase database (realtime db or firestore or cloud storage, whichever you're using).

Here's a link to get you started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules